# std::cout with floating number

Tags: c++

I'm using visual studio 2015 to print two floating numbers:

```
double d1 = 1.5;
double d2 = 123456.789;

std::cout << "value1: " << d1 << std::endl;
std::cout << "value2: " << d2 << std::endl;

std::cout << "maximum number of significant decimal digits (value1): " << -std::log10(std::nextafter(d1, std::numeric_limits<double>::max()) - d1) << std::endl;
std::cout << "maximum number of significant decimal digits (value2): " << -std::log10(std::nextafter(d2, std::numeric_limits<double>::max()) - d2) << std::endl;
```

This prints the following:

```
value1: 1.5
value2: 123457
maximum number of significant decimal digits (value1): 15.6536
maximum number of significant decimal digits (value2): 10.8371
```

Why `123457` is printed out for the value `123456.789`? Does ANSI C++ specification allow to display anything for floating numbers when `std::cout` is used without `std::setprecision()`?

Comment: " Does ANSI C++ specification allow to display anything for floating numbers when std::cout is used without std::setprecision()?" yes it does.

Comment: @Hermantas, right I mean std::cout.

Comment: @Mats, why the specification is so vague on this subject? It would help developers if the specification is more specific (like print the floating number with its significant digits). Something like printf("%.16g\n", d).

Comment: The default precision is 6, just like for printf.

Comment: @Bo, right std::cout.precision() gives 6. So the specification is well defined. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The rounding off happens because of the C++ standard which can be seen by writing
`std::cout<<std::cout.precision();`

The output screen will show `6` which tells that the default number of significant digits which will be printed by the `std::cout` statement is `6`. That is why it automatically rounds off the floating number to 6 digits.

Answer (score 12):

What you have have pointed out is actually one of those many things that the standardization committee should consider regarding the `standard iostream` in C++. Such things work well when you write :-

```
printf ("%f\n", d2);
```

But not with `std::cout` where you need to use `std::setprecision` because it's formatting is similar to the use of `%g` instead of `%f` in `printf`. So you need to write :-

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << "value2: " << d2 << std::endl;
```

But if you dont like this method & are using C++11 (& onwards) then you can also write :-

```
std::cout << "value2: " << std::to_string(d2) << std::endl;
```

This will give you the same result as `printf ("%f\n", d2);`.

A much better method is to cancel the rounding that occurs in `std::cout` by using `std::fixed` :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::fixed;
    double d = 123456.789;
    std::cout << d;
    return 0;
}
```

Output :-

```
123456.789000
```

So I guess your problem is solved !!

Comment: Right, printf ("%f", d) displays a floating number with 6 decimal digits. std::cout displays a floating number with a maximum of 6 digits (including digits before and after the decimal point). I was confused as I didn't know about this default precision. Now all is clear... Thanks.

Comment: Interesting, I did not realize that float arguments to printf are actually doubles.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem here is that the C++ standard is not written to be easy to read, it is written to be precise and not repeat itself. So if you look up the `operator<<(double)`, it doesn't say anything other than "it uses `num_put` - because that is how the `cout << some_float_value` is implemented.

The default behaviour is what `print("%g", value);` does [table 88 in n3337 version of the C++ standard explains what the equivalence of printf and c++ formatting]. So if you want to do `%.16g` you need to change the precision by calling `setprecision(16)`.