# Output must be decimal

Tags: c++, hex, display

I want to display 265612.2 how ever the output still 265612

I input : 4.2

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a;
    double b;
  
    cout<<"Enter the number of light year : ";
    cin>>a;
    b = a * 63241;
    cout<<b;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::cout with floating number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33854825/stdcout-with-floating-number)

Answer (score 0):

You need to "manipulate" the output stream (`std::cout`):

```
#include <iomanip>     // manipulating helpers
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    double a;
    double b;

    std::cout<<"Enter the number of light year : ";
    if(std::cin >> a) {
        std::cout << std::setprecision(1)  // one decimal
                  << std::fixed;           // fixed precision

        b = a * 63241.01;

        std::cout << b;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n37oaYvaM)

Comment: Sorry for the wrong details. I've already edit some of my code.
I want to display 265612.2 how ever the output still 265612 I input : 4.2

#include

using namespace std;

int main() {

double a;
double b;




cout<<"Enter the number of light year : ";
cin>>a;
b = a * 63241;
cout<<b;

return 0;
}

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Yes sir. Im still a newbie I can't understand the  std::cout I'm sorry.

Comment: Yes sir it works. However User must be free on inputting the lightyear number instead of fix data.

Comment: @Bajas I added a demo to the answer where the input is taken from the input stream (`std::cin`). With some decoration: https://godbolt.org/z/s43jxhjs7

Comment: Hi Sir It works!. THANK YOU VERYY MUCH. I've learned a lot from this.